# Three.js - Uncaught ReferenceError: OBJLoader is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm following several tutorials on Three.js, yet I keep getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: OBJLoader is not defined` error when trying to implement my own .obj file. Tried different methods, nothing is helping. Been stuck on this problem for days.

I'm running on localhost using http-server.

Oddly enough, when I switch the `new OBJLoader();` to `new THREE.ObjectLoader();` it seems to work as it tries to load the file, albeit the file is not a .json file, it is an .obj so it throws an error.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>three.js crash course</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="js/three.min.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize(width, height);
        camera.aspect = width/height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    });

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    const loader = new OBJLoader();

    loader.load (
        // resource URL
        './models/boat_large.obj',
        // called when resource is loaded
        function ( object ) {

            scene.add( object );

        },
        // called when loading is in progresses
        function ( xhr ) {

            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

        },
        // called when loading has errors
        function ( error ) {

            console.log( 'An error happened' );

        }
    );

    camera.position.z = 3;

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.8);


    // game logic
    var update = () => {
    
    };

    // draw scene
    var render = () => {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    // run game loop (update, render, repeat)
    var GameLoop = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(GameLoop);
    
        update();
        render();
    }

    GameLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `new THREE.OBJLoader()` when you reference the javascript files like that.

The reason it works in the ThreeJS example is, because it is imported via

```
import { OBJLoader } from './jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';
```

.

Alternatively you could include the file like it is shown in the [example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/350f0a021943d6fa1d039a7c14c303653daa463f/examples/webgl_loader_obj.html#L19)
.
In your case it would obviously be something like

```
import { OBJLoader } from '../loaders/OBJLoader.js';
```

assuming the JS posted above is from `index.js`.

Comment: I've tried doing it that way. I replaced with `new THREE.OBJLoader()` and I get `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OBJLoader is not a constructor`. I also tried to add the `import` right after `window.onload` and I get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: I tried adding the `import` before the `window.onload` and it doesn't give me the `Unexpected token` error anymore, but I still get the `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OBJLoader is not a constructor`

Comment: If you add the `import` **before** the `window.onload` you need to use `new OBJLoader();`.

Comment: I managed to get it to work, thank you! But now I'm getting a `THREE.OBJLoader: Rendering identifier "usemap" not supported. Textures must be defined in MTL files` :/

Comment: Well I think that is pretty self-explanatory, isn't it?
Otherwise please open another question after you researched this.

Comment: Obj finally loads now, I was just zoomed in. It's missing colors which I assume is the texture error, which I will figure out. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

it worked for me adding the following import:

```
import {OBJLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader';
```